# basics of a reverse proxy? what am I missing?

Tags: reverse-proxy

I am no server admin, just a web developer trying to act as such. :)

We have website A and website B.   Website A has a subdomain called subby.websitea.com, which connects via A name to ANOTHER server.   I was told that in order to make subby.websitea.com APPEAR as a subFOLDER of website A (ie. websitea.com/subby/) than a reverse proxy is needed.

well, I've been looking at documentation all night and I just.... I don't get the basics! My host was kind enough to set up our VPS with the info outlined here: http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

But... then what!?  How do I make this work?  Do I now edit the htaccess file? I haven't found a good simple explanation of how it works. I love learning, but I think I have to get over this basic hump first.... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's part (or all of it?) of your question, a reverse proxy is basically a gateway, or intermediary between a server and its clients. Requests are sent to the reverse proxy, and it (the reverse-proxy) forwards them to the server. 
There are lots of other features on a reverse, like load-balancing and caching. I guess a Google search should point you to more resources and documentations on the matter.

As I understand it, you have two websites (subby.websitea.com / www.websitea.com) and you want 'www.websitea.com/subby' to forward to "subby.websitea.com".

EDITED PART: You have access to Apache config, so you need to enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http in httpd.conf. Then uncomment

```
Include extra/httpd-vhost.conf
```

(in http.conf, at the end of the file).

You must then edit the httpd-vhost.conf file to add your proxy directives.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
/* Other default config like Documentroot, etc */
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /subby/ http://subby.websitea.com/
ProxyPassReverse /subby/ http://subby.websitea.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, everything that comes in http://www.websitea.com/subby/ would be forwarded to http://subby.websitea.com without the adress getting altered.

EDIT AGAIN: I forgot to say: remember to restart Apache each time you change something in the .conf files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the attempt, but it didn't really answer my question.  :P

I DID say I have a VPS, so yes, I have full control over the apache and everything in it.

And I also posted that same exact link you did. And yes, it told me "configurations", but it didnt say what to DO with those configurations.

I believe you have it backwards though. I do NOT want the subdomain... THIS is what I want to accomplish:

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/what-is-a-reverse-proxy-and-how-can-it-help-my-seo

Comment: I'm embarrassed I misread two important points in your question and I'm sorry for it. I'm editing my previous answer right now.

Comment: haha, no problem.  I guess I need to learn how to use shell access, don't I? lol.  Im going to go ahead and vote you up on this one and give her the ole college try.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http

`# a2enmod proxy_http` this should also enable mod_proxy as a dependency.

Create a new VirtualHosts file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/subby.websitea.com` with the content:

```
<virtualhost *>
  ServerName subby.websitea.com
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.15/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.15/
</virtualhost>
```

Enable the new site:

`a2ensite subby.websitea.com`

Reload Apache:

`service apace2 reload`

Done.