# Apache change vhost to forward name to external IP address

Tags: apache

I'm running Linux (Mac OSX) and MAMP. I want to set up my vhosts to point www.example.com to a specific external IP address 78.123.123.123.

How do I do this?

I've got as far as:
changing my etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       www.example.com
```

and adding this to my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "89.111.119.119"
ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Comment: You need a reverse proxy for this. You should check out this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270956/basics-of-a-reverse-proxy-what-am-i-missing

Answer (score 0):

I was totally overthinking on this (or underthinking!?).

I just needed to change the hosts file:

```
99.99.99.99       www.example.com
```